# Mongo doesn't run after installing on Docker Centos image: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running a CentOS image with multiple dependencies for my app, one of which is mongo. All other dependencies seem to run when I run the image.  However, mongo service does not seem to run. I have seen similar problems (not related to docker) but none of those solutions worked for me. My host machine is an Ubuntu 16.04 if its of any use knowing that. Here are the deets:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install initscripts

RUN yum -y install systemd; yum clean all; \
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ “/sys/fs/cgroup” ]
CMD [“/usr/sbin/init”]


# Compilers and related tools:
RUN yum groupinstall -y "development tools"

# Libraries needed during compilation to enable all features of Python:
RUN yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel expat-devel

# If you are on a clean "minimal" install of CentOS you also need the wget tool:
RUN yum install -y wget

# Python 3.6.0:
RUN wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
RUN tar xf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
RUN cd Python-3.6.0 && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib" && make && make altinstall
RUN mkdir -p /opt/python/Python-3.3/
RUN ln -s /opt/python/Python-3.3/python python3.6

#MongoDb
ADD  mongodb-org-3.0.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo
RUN yum install -y mongodb-org
EXPOSE 27017

#Phantom JS
RUN wget http://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
RUN mkdir -p /opt/phantomjs
RUN tar xvfj phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
RUN cd phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 && cp -ar * /opt/phantomjs/. && ln -s /opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs && phantomjs -v

#JINJA
RUN python3.6 -m pip install Jinja2

CMD /usr/bin/mongod
```

Docker Version:

```
Client:
Version:      17.03.1-ce
API version:  1.27
Go version:   go1.7.5
Git commit:   c6d412e
Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      17.03.1-ce
API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:   go1.7.5
Git commit:   c6d412e
Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Experimental: false
```

The error I get when I run the mongo command when running a contaier after building the Dockerfile is:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.14
connecting to: test
2017-05-04T11:27:33.199+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-05-04T11:27:33.203+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run with `-p 27017:27017`? Also, from where are you running the mongo client?

Comment: Which CMD are you trying to use? You define CMD as init, but later redefine it as mongod.

Comment: replace `CMD /usr/bin/mongod` with `ENTRYPOINT service mongod start`

Comment: Your first check for whether the mongod service is running should be the container status and logs, not the mongo client; there are many problems which could get in the way of the mongo client connecting, even if the service is running happily.

Comment: Try running with flag `--bind_ip_all`